# Can't read data with Retrofit to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, retrofit

I try to get data from the URL and transfer it to Fragment. The program works but as a result, nothing is displayed. I think it is because  I am transferring data incorrectly. But I don't know how to fix it.
my controller class:

```
public class Controller implements Callback<News> {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://news.com/wwer/";
    private ApiInterface apiInterface;
    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    public Controller(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }
    public void start() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<News> news = apiInterface.getNews();
        news.enqueue(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<News> call, Response<News> response) {
        News news = response.body();

        String sourceName = news.getSources().get(1).getName();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("sourceName", sourceName);

        FragmentManager fm = mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        NameFragment fragmentCurrent = new NameFragment();
        fragmentCurrent.setArguments(bundle);
        ft.add(R.id.fragment,fragmentCurrent);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<News> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d("error", "can't parse data: ", t);
    }
}
```

and my fragment class:

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.name_fragment, container, false);
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.news_names_list);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        String sourcNam = bundle.getString("sourceName");

        textView.setText(sourcNam);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<News> call, Response<News> response) {
    ...
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    ...
}
```

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    ...
}
```

These two bundles that you create using `new` keyword are two absolutely different objects. It means if you put in one bundle some argument the other bundle will not contain it.

#### Solution

What you need to modify is how you extract the value from a bundle that you used as the argument to the `fragment.setArguments(...)` method.

The opposite of the `setArguments` is the `getArguments` method that returns you the bundle object you set.

*Remember, that `getArguments` can return `null` if you do not call `setArguments` before using the `getArguments`. In your case we could say that you should always use `setArguments` before committing a fragment transaction.*

```
public class NameFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.name_fragment, container, false);
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.news_names_list);
        
        String sourcNam = getArguments().getString("sourceName");

        textView.setText(sourcNam);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your advice. Now in fragment class I do this: `Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle!=null) {
            String sourcNam = bundle.getString("sourceName");
            textView.setText(sourcNam);
        }`

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu need help here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64495233/retrofit-call-inside-an-adapter-in-android